# Javascript: Select Textarea, Type then Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this sounds a little stup.. but I would like to know if I can create a javascript that can automate some simple commands so that I can easily test some feature in the webpage I am making. Let's say that I have a text area in my page that looks like:

```
<textarea class="some-class"></textarea>
```

Now I would like to open the javascript console and paste a command that does the following:

1. Sets focus on the text-area.
2. Changes the value of the textarea
3. Simulate a keypress "Enter" in the keyboard.

I know I could use some other automation like Selenium but this is just a simple task that I would like to shortcut. How can I do this? I prefer pure javascript but can also work using jquery if its really required.

Comment: Just call a function from the console....

Comment: @Eric I would like to create that function in the console as well but writing the function that does the steps I described above is my main problem as I have poor javascript knowledge as of now

Comment: Could you help me write a javascript that focuses a text area, adding value and simulating a Enter keypress on the keyboard? @Eric

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery it's pretty easy to do this:

```js
function example() {
  $('.mytextarea')
    .focus()              // Sets focus on the text-area
    .val('CHANGE')        // Changes the value of the textarea
    .trigger("keydown", { // Trigger Enter (key 13) 
      which: 13
    });     
}

$('button').on('click', example);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
<button type="button">Run</button>
```

If you want each event to be fully processed before the next one happens, you can make each step async:

```js
function step(cb, text) {
  $('#step').text(`${text}...`);
  return new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      cb();
      resolve();
    }, 500)
  );
}

function example() {
  const $textarea = $('.mytextarea')
  step(() => $textarea.focus(), 'focusing')
  .then(() =>
    step(() => $textarea.val('CHANGE'), 'changing')
  )
  .then(() =>
    step(() => $textarea.trigger("keydown", {
      which: 13
    }), 'triggering')
  );
}

$('button').on('click', example);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
<button type="button">Run</button>
<i id="step"></i>
```

Comment: This may or may not be a problem, depending on what's being tested here, but it's worth noting that triggering a keydown event just fires the event -- it doesn't insert the character into the `textarea` (so in this example no newline is inserted even though a keydown event for keyCode 13 fires.)